# Unable to delete value from HashTable in C

Tags: c, hash

I'm trying to delete a value from hash table, the code works when I delete a value from the array where the linked list size is one, then segfaults if the size is greater than 1.

```
typedef struct hash {
    char *key;
    char *value;
    struct hash *next;
} hashTable;

// generate hash code
unsigned int hashCode(char *key) {
    int sum;
    int i;

    sum = 0;
    i = 0;
    while (key[i])
        sum += key[i++];
    return sum % MAX_HASH;
}

// get hash item size
int hash_size(hashTable *head) {
    int i;
    hashTable *list;

    i = 0;
    list = head;
    if (list) {
        while (list != NULL) {
            i++;
            list = list->next;
        }
    }
    return (i);
}

// free item
void free_hash(hashTable *item) {
    free(item->key);
    free(item->value);
    free(item);
}

// function for deleting item from hash table
void deleteItem(hashTable *table[], char *key) {
    hashTable *head = table[hashCode(key)];
    hashTable *tmp = head;
    hashTable *prev = NULL;

    if (!head)
        return;

    if (hash_size(tmp) == 1) {
        table[hashCode(key)] = 0;
        free_hash(tmp);
        return;
    }
    while (strcmp(tmp->key, key) != 0 && tmp->next != NULL) {
        prev = tmp;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }

    if (strcmp(tmp->key, key) == 0) {
        if (prev)
            prev->next = tmp->next;
        else
            head = tmp->next;
        free_hash(tmp);
    }
}

// function for inserting item into the table
void insert(hashTable *table[], char *key, char *value) {
    hashTable *tmp;
    hashTable *item;
    unsigned int code;

    item = (hashTable *)malloc(sizeof(hashTable));
    if (!item)
        return;
    item->key = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(key) + 1);
    item->value = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(value) + 1);
    item->next = NULL;
    code = hashCode(key);
    strcpy(item->key, key);
    strcpy(item->value, value);
    if (!table[code])
        table[code] = item;
    else {
        tmp = table[code];
        item->next = tmp;
        table[code] = item;
    }
}

// displaying items
void display(hashTable *table[]) {
    int i = 0;
    hashTable *tmp;

    while (i < MAX_HASH) {
        if (table[i] != NULL) {
            tmp = table[i];
            if (hash_size(tmp) == 1)
                printf("%s=%s\n", tmp->key, tmp->value);
            else {
                while (tmp != NULL) {
                    printf("%s=%s\n", tmp->key, tmp->value);
                    tmp = tmp->next;
                }
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    hashTable *table[MAX_HASH];

    memset(table, 0, MAX_HASH * sizeof(hashTable *));
    insert(table, "Bart", "first");
    insert(table, "Lisa", "Second");
    insert(table, "Foo", "bar");
    deleteItem(table, "Lisa");
    display(table);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @PaulR thank you, which debugger do you recommend I use?

Comment: It depends on what OS, toolchain, etc you are using - but gdb would be a good choice if you're using anything other than Windows and not using an IDE.

Comment: Many compilers have a matching debugger. Paul is talking about the gcc/gdb pair.  You may also need special compiler options to get proper debug code in your object code.

Comment: Thanks, I just ran the program with `valgrind` and I'm getting `Invalid read` within `free_hash` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many issues in your code:

- do include the standard header files, and define `HASH_MAX`:

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>

  #define HASH_MAX  1027
  ```
- the type `hashTable` is confusing: it is really an entry list, the hash table itself is the array.
- the `while` loops are error prone: use the much preferred `for` loops where the initialization, test and increment of the loop index are conveniently located on the same line:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < HASH_MAX; i++) {
      // printf hashTable[i]
  }
  ```

  I know the local style conventions at `42` explicitly exclude the `for` loop, but you should lobby against this questionable choice.
- there is no need to special case `hash_size(tmp) == 1` in `display_table()`
- there is no need to cast the return value of `malloc()`. `sizeof(char)` is `1` by definition.  You could use `strdup()` to duplicate C strings.
- in `deleteItem()` you always remove the entry if it is alone: this is incorrect if the entry has a different key. Furthermore, you do not link the previous node or the table slot to the next element of the list.

Here is a corrected version of this function:

```
// function for deleting item from hash table
void deleteItem(hashTable *table[], const char *key) {
    hashTable **link = &table[hashCode(key)];

    while (*link) {
        hashTable *tmp = *link;
        if (strcmp(tmp->key, key) == 0) {
            *link = tmp->next;  // unlink the list node
            free_hash(tmp);
            break;  // remove this if you mean for deleteItem to remove all matching nodes
        } else {
            link = &(*link)->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a simplified version of the whole program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_HASH  1027

typedef struct HashItem {
    char *key;
    char *value;
    struct HashItem *next;
} HashItem;

// generate hash code
unsigned int hashCode(const char *key) {
    unsigned int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; key[i]; i++) {
        sum += (unsigned char)key[i] * (i + 1);
    }
    return sum % MAX_HASH;
}

// free item
void freeItem(HashItem *item) {
    free(item->key);
    free(item->value);
    free(item);
}

// function for deleting item from hash table
void deleteItem(HashItem *table[], const char *key) {
    HashItem **link = &table[hashCode(key)];

    while (*link) {
        HashItem *tmp = *link;
        if (strcmp(tmp->key, key) == 0) {
            *link = tmp->next;  // unlink the list node
            freeItem(tmp);
            break;
        } else {
            link = &(*link)->next;
        }
    }
}

// function for inserting item into the table
void insertItem(HashItem *table[], const char *key, const char *value) {
    unsigned int code = hashCode(key);
    HashItem *item = malloc(sizeof(*item));
    if (item != NULL) {
        item->key = strdup(key);
        item->value = strdup(value);
        item->next = table[code];
        table[code] = item;
    }
}

// displaying items
void displayHashTable(HashItem *table[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_HASH; i++) {
        for (HashItem *tmp = table[i]; tmp; tmp = tmp->next) {
            printf("%s=%s\n", tmp->key, tmp->value);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    HashItem *table[MAX_HASH] = { 0 };

    insertItem(table, "Bart", "first");
    insertItem(table, "Lisa", "Second");
    insertItem(table, "Foo", "bar");
    deleteItem(table, "Lisa");
    displayHashTable(table);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also purely on style, the random mixture of `camelCase` and `under_score` naming for identifiers in deeply disturbing. ;-)

Comment: @PaulR: yes indeed. I removed that from my proposed simpler version